# Flatten a nested list of variable sized sublists into a SciPy array

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

How can I use numpy/scipy to flatten a nested list with sublists of different sizes? Speed is very important and the lists are large.

```
 lst = [[1, 2, 3, 4],[2, 3],[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],[4, 1, 2]]
```

Is anything faster than this?

```
 vec = sp.array(list(*chain(lst)))
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

How about [np.fromiter](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromiter.html):

```
In [49]: %timeit np.hstack(lst*1000)
10 loops, best of 3: 25.2 ms per loop

In [50]: %timeit np.array(list(chain.from_iterable(lst*1000)))
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.81 ms per loop

In [52]: %timeit np.fromiter(chain.from_iterable(lst*1000), dtype='int')
1000 loops, best of 3: 1 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 8):

You can try [numpy.hstack](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html)

```
>>> lst = [[1, 2, 3, 4],[2, 3],[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],[4, 1, 2]]
>>> np.hstack(lst)
array([1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 1, 2])
```

Answer (score 6):

The fastest way to create a numpy array from an iterator is to use `numpy.fromiter`:

```
>>> %timeit numpy.fromiter(itertools.chain.from_iterable(lst), numpy.int64)
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.76 us per loop
>>> %timeit numpy.array(list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(lst)))
100000 loops, best of 3: 14.5 us per loop
>>> %timeit numpy.hstack(lst)
10000 loops, best of 3: 57.7 us per loop
```

As you can see, this is faster than converting to a list, and much faster than `hstack`.

Answer (score 3):

How about trying:

```
np.hstack(lst)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`chain.from_iterable`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable):

```
vec = sp.array(list(chain.from_iterable(lst)))
```

This avoids using `*` which is quite expensive to handle if the iterable has many sublists.

An other option *might* be to `sum` the lists:

```
vec = sp.array(sum(lst, []))
```

Note however that this will cause [quadratic reallocation](http://www.python.org/doc/essays/list2str.html). Something like this performs *much* better:

```
def sum_lists(lst):
    if len(lst) < 2:
        return sum(lst, [])
    else:
        half_length = len(lst) // 2
        return sum_lists(lst[:half_length]) + sum_lists(lst[half_length:])
```

On my machine I get:

```
>>> L = [[random.randint(0, 500) for _ in range(x)] for x in range(10, 510)]
>>> timeit.timeit('sum(L, [])', 'from __main__ import L', number=1000)
168.3029818534851
>>> timeit.timeit('sum_lists(L)', 'from __main__ import L,sum_lists', number=1000)
10.248489141464233
>>> 168.3029818534851 / 10.248489141464233
16.422223757114615
```

As you can see, a 16x speed-up. The `chain.from_iterable` is even faster:

```
>>> timeit.timeit('list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(L))', 'import itertools; from __main__ import L', number=1000)
1.905594825744629
>>> 10.248489141464233 / 1.905594825744629
5.378105042586658
```

An other 6x speed-up.

---

I looked for a "pure-python" solution, not knowing numpy. I believe <s>Abhijit</s>unutbu/senderle's solution is the way to go in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Use a function to flatten the list

```
>>> flatten = lambda x: [y for l in x for y in flatten(l)] if type(x) is list else [x]
>>> flatten(lst)
```