# Nested List to List

Tags: python, list, nested

How would I go about making a list like

```
My_list = [['Item1', 'item2'], ['shark', 'dog', 'cat']]
```

To two lists like the following:

```
My_list = ['Item1', 'item2']
My_list2 = ['shark', 'dog', 'cat']
```

Also, how would I go about doing this if I didn't know how many lists were in the list?

Comment: What exactly is the meaning of `My_list = ['Item1', 'item2']['shark', 'dog', 'cat']`? It is not a valid expression.

Comment: If you wanted `My_list = ['Item1', 'item2', 'shark', 'dog', 'cat']` then the answer is: `sum(My_list,[])` or `list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(My_list))`.
See also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15366053/flatten-a-nested-list-of-variable-sized-sublists-into-a-scipy-array) related question.

Comment: Sorry, revised the question was a little confused art what I was asking lol.

Comment: please use lowercase variable names

Answer (score 1):

You can use sequence unpacking:

```
My_list, My_list2 = My_list
```

If `My_list` can have more elements and you wanted to do something like:

```
for elem in My_list:
    create_variable('My_listn', elem)
```

This is **not** possible in the general case. Python doesn't allow creating locals at runtime(at least not reliably).

Comment: Do I need to import the create_variable function? It says global name 'create_variable' is not defined

Comment: @VEDYL No, that's pseudocode. What I wanted to say is that you *can't* create variables at runtime. You can create global variables using `globals()['variable_name'] = value`, but this *doesn't* work for variables inside functions.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `My_list` is really meant to look like:

```
My_list = [['Item1', 'item2'], ['shark', 'dog', 'cat']]
```

And also that you truly want what you are asking for, you could do something like:

```
My_list2 = My_list[1]
My_list = My_List[0]
```

Or, alternatively, as others are suggesting, you could use list unpacking:

```
My_list, My_list2 = My_list
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> My_list = [['Item1', 'item2'], ['shark', 'dog', 'cat']]
>>> l1, l2 = My_list
>>> l1
['Item1', 'item2']
>>> l2
['shark', 'dog', 'cat']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
My_list, My_list2 = My_list[0], My_list[1]
```

Comment: Cheers, just curious, how would I do this if I didn't know how long the list was. So say the list was [['Item1', 'item2'], ['shark', 'dog', 'cat']['added', 'silly', 'cant', 'think']] but we didn't know there 3 lists inside of the list

Comment: you can't have unknown number of local variables - in that case you use list (which you already have)

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> My_list = ['Item1', 'item2'],['shark', 'dog', 'cat']
>>> My_list
(['Item1', 'item2'], ['shark', 'dog', 'cat'])
>>> len(My_list)
2

>>> My_list[0]
['Item1', 'item2']
>>> My_list[1]
['shark', 'dog', 'cat']

>>> My_list[2]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#34>", line 1, in <module>
    My_list[2]
 IndexError: tuple index out of range

>>> My_list, My_list2 = My_list
>>> My_list
['Item1', 'item2']
>>> My_list2
['shark', 'dog', 'cat']
```