# Numpy max slow when applied to list of arrays

Tags: python, numpy

I carry out some computations to obtain a list of numpy arrays. Subsequently, I would like to find the largest values along the first axis. My current implementation (see below) is very slow and I would like to find alternatives.

**Original**

```
pending = [<list of items>]
matrix = [compute(item) for item in pending if <some condition on item>]
dominant = np.max(matrix, axis = 0)
```

**Revision 1:** This implementation is faster (~10x; presumably because numpy does not need to figure out the shape of the array)

```
pending = [<list of items>]
matrix = [compute(item) for item in pending if <some condition on item>]
matrix = np.vstack(matrix)
dominant = np.max(matrix, axis = 0)
```

I ran a couple of tests and the slowdown seems to be due to an internal conversion of the list of arrays to a numpy array

```
 Timer unit: 1e-06 s
 Total time: 1.21389 s
 Line # Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
 ==============================================================
 4                                           def direct_max(list_of_arrays):
 5      1000      1213886   1213.9    100.0      np.max(list_of_arrays, axis = 0)

 Total time: 1.20766 s
 Line # Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
 ==============================================================
 8                                           def numpy_max(list_of_arrays):
 9      1000      1151281   1151.3     95.3      list_of_arrays = np.array(list_of_arrays)
10      1000        56384     56.4      4.7      np.max(list_of_arrays, axis = 0)

Total time: 0.15437 s
Line # Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
12                                           @profile
13                                           def stack_max(list_of_arrays):
14      1000       102205    102.2     66.2      list_of_arrays = np.vstack(list_of_arrays)
15      1000        52165     52.2     33.8      np.max(list_of_arrays, axis = 0)
```

Is there any way to speed up the max function or is it possible to populate a numpy array efficiently with the results of my calculation such that max is fast?

Comment: What datatype are `items`?

Comment: The fastest way would be to start in the first place with a 2d numpy array instead of a list of arrays. If the lists have different lengths, just pad with -inf or nan.

Comment: @mgilson: The items themselves are key-value-pairs of the form (key: some hashable type, value: numpy array)

Comment: @Bitwise: Yes, that would be ideal. However, I need to process the items sequentially. What is the best way of doing that with a numpy array?

Comment: Can you hint us what processing you are doing?

Comment: @Jaime: I am carrying out convolutions of the <items> with another numpy array. In particular, I am using the FFTW3 python bindings.

Comment: Can't you still populate the numpy 2d array sequentially?

Comment: @Bitwise: I will give it a shot. The problem is that I will need to make two passes over the data. First, to determine the number of items. Second, to populate the array.

Comment: I believe `vstack` is pretty slow. I remember a question about converting lists to numpy arrays it was clearly slower than other solutions. Edit: No, it was about flattening a list, in which case `np.fromitem` was much faster than `hstack`.

Comment: @Bakuriu but `vstack` (and `hstack`, et al.) are faster than just `array` or `asarray`, clearly. Possibly because of their handling of shape mismatches (`array` makes 1d array of dtype `object`)?

Comment: @askewchan See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15366053/flatten-a-nested-list-of-variable-sized-sublists-into-a-scipy-array) for the proof of the opposite: `np.array` is **faster** than `hstack`.

Comment: @Bakuriu Strange, not on my machine:  `a = [np.arange(i,i+2*n) for i in xrange(n)]`; 
`np.array(a): 309 ms per loop`; 
`np.vstack(a): 20.2 ms per loop`; See also OP's timines for proof that in OP's case, `vstack` takes 102 and `array` takes 1151 (dunno the units).  I'm not claiming to understand this though :P  Maybe for 2d lists, `stack` is faster, for 1d, `array` is faster; again due to possible shape mismatches?

Comment: @askewchan - clearly not a good day for me to be writing code :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `reduce(np.maximum, matrix)`, here is a test:

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(0)

N, M = 1000, 1000
matrix = [np.random.rand(N) for _ in xrange(M)]

%timeit np.max(matrix, axis = 0)
%timeit np.max(np.vstack(matrix), axis = 0)
%timeit reduce(np.maximum, matrix)
```

The result is:

```
10 loops, best of 3: 116 ms per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 10.6 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 3.66 ms per loop
```

**Edit**

`argmax()' is more difficult, but you can use a for loop:

```
def argmax_list(matrix):
    m = matrix[0].copy()
    idx = np.zeros(len(m), dtype=np.int)
    for i, a in enumerate(matrix[1:], 1):
        mask = m < a
        m[mask] = a[mask]
        idx[mask] = i
    return idx
```

It's still faster than `argmax()`:

```
%timeit np.argmax(matrix, axis=0)
%timeit np.argmax(np.vstack(matrix), axis=0)
%timeit argmax_list(matrix)
```

result:

```
10 loops, best of 3: 131 ms per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 21 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 13.1 ms per loop
```

Comment: That's great. One more question: Do you have a suggestion how to emulate the behaviour of `np.argmax` using the same methodology?