# Construct single numpy array from smaller arrays of different sizes

Tags: python, arrays, optimization, numpy

I have an array of values, *x*. Given 'start' and 'stop' indices, I need to construct an array *y* using sub-arrays of *x*.

```
import numpy as np
x = np.arange(20)
start = np.array([2, 8, 15])
stop = np.array([5, 10, 20])
nsubarray = len(start)
```

Where I would like *y* to be:

```
y = array([ 2,  3,  4,  8,  9, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19])
```

(In practice the arrays I am using are much larger).

One way to construct *y* is using a list comprehension, but the list needs to be flattened afterwards:

```
import itertools as it
y = [x[start[i]:stop[i]] for i in range(nsubarray)]
y = np.fromiter(it.chain.from_iterable(y), dtype=int)
```

I found that it is actually faster to use a for-loop:

```
y = np.empty(sum(stop - start), dtype = int)
a = 0
for i in range(nsubarray):
    b = a + stop[i] - start[i]
    y[a:b] = x[start[i]:stop[i]]
    a = b
```

I was wondering if anyone knows of a way that I can optimize this? Thank you very much!

**EDIT**

The following tests all of the times:

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.random as rd
import itertools as it


def get_chunks(arr, start, stop):
    rng = stop - start
    rng = rng[rng!=0]      #Need to add this in case of zero sized ranges
    np.cumsum(rng, out=rng)
    inds = np.ones(rng[-1], dtype=np.int)
    inds[rng[:-1]] = start[1:]-stop[:-1]+1
    inds[0] = start[0]
    np.cumsum(inds, out=inds)
    return np.take(arr, inds)


def for_loop(arr, start, stop):
    y = np.empty(sum(stop - start), dtype = int)
    a = 0
    for i in range(nsubarray):
        b = a + stop[i] - start[i]
        y[a:b] = arr[start[i]:stop[i]]
        a = b
    return y

xmax = 1E6
nsubarray = 100000
x = np.arange(xmax)
start = rd.randint(0, xmax - 10, nsubarray)
stop = start + 10
```

Which results in:

```
In [379]: %timeit np.hstack([x[i:j] for i,j in it.izip(start, stop)])
1 loops, best of 3: 410 ms per loop

In [380]: %timeit for_loop(x, start, stop)
1 loops, best of 3: 281 ms per loop

In [381]: %timeit np.concatenate([x[i:j] for i,j in it.izip(start, stop)])
10 loops, best of 3: 97.8 ms per loop

In [382]: %timeit get_chunks(x, start, stop)
100 loops, best of 3: 16.6 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bit complicated, but quite fast. Basically what we do is create the index list based off vector addition and the use `np.take` instead of any python loops:

```
def get_chunks(arr, start, stop):
     rng = stop - start
     rng = rng[rng!=0]      #Need to add this in case of zero sized ranges
     np.cumsum(rng, out=rng)
     inds = np.ones(rng[-1], dtype=np.int)
     inds[rng[:-1]] = start[1:]-stop[:-1]+1
     inds[0] = start[0]
     np.cumsum(inds, out=inds)
     return np.take(arr, inds)
```

Check that it is returning the correct result:

```
xmax = 1E6
nsubarray = 100000
x = np.arange(xmax)
start = np.random.randint(0, xmax - 10, nsubarray)
stop = start + np.random.randint(1, 10, nsubarray)

old = np.concatenate([x[b:e] for b, e in izip(start, stop)])
new = get_chunks(x, start, stop)
np.allclose(old,new)
True
```

Some timings:

```
%timeit np.hstack([x[i:j] for i,j in zip(start, stop)])
1 loops, best of 3: 354 ms per loop

%timeit np.concatenate([x[b:e] for b, e in izip(start, stop)])
10 loops, best of 3: 119 ms per loop

%timeit get_chunks(x, start, stop)
100 loops, best of 3: 7.59 ms per loop
```

Comment: Wow thanks so much, this is definitely the fastest one. I've edited the main post!

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps using `zip`, `np.arange` and `np.hstack`:

```
np.hstack([np.arange(i, j) for i,j in zip(start, stop)])
```

Comment: I tried this, but it's a bit slower than the loop -- see my edit above.

Comment: Faster than the loop for me if I use `np.hstack([x[i:j] for i,j in izip(start, stop)])`

Comment: And this is marginally faster: `np.hstack(map(lambda i,j: x[i:j], start, stop))`

Comment: @askewchan -- this definitely improves the performance, but for me it is still slower than the loop, I've edited my main post.

Comment: @turnerm, clearly the differences are small then. Perhaps you should use the one you like the most.  On my computer, I get `30.2 µs per loop` for the for-loop, and `24.3 µs per loop` for the lambda-map.  I'm sure they scale differently, and I'm just testing with the small example you've posted.

Comment: @askewchan You are right that the differences are indeed small, and I suppose I should have specified that I am interested in performance on larger arrays (such as those in my edit). For my situation, any small improvement would help a lot, so it looks like the for-loop is my best bet at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

This is almost 3 times faster than the loop for me, almost all the time difference comes from replacing fromiter with concatenate:

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import izip

y = [x[b:e] for b, e in izip(start, stop)]
y = np.concatenate(y)
```

Comment: Thanks so much, that absolutely works! I was blindly following this post to flatten my list: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22326882/construct-single-numpy-array-from-smaller-arrays-of-different-sizes

Comment: That link is to yourself.

Comment: Oh whoops, I meant this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15366053/flatten-a-nested-list-of-variable-sized-sublists-into-a-scipy-array

Answer (score 0):

Would it be okay using slices instead of np.arrays?

```
import numpy as np
x = np.arange(10)
start = slice(2, 8)
stop = slice(5, 10)

print np.concatenate((x[start], x[stop]))
```

Comment: I have not tried that, although I am not sure if this method is practical for 100,000's of slices (which is what I am really dealing with unfortunately). I will give it a shot though, and post timings.

By the way, I don't think my explanation of 'start' and 'stop' were totally clear, see my edit, i.e., in your example it should be:
    `s1 = slice(2,5)`,
    `s2 = slice(8,10)`,
    `y = np.concatenate((x[s1], x[s2]))`